# How to add Google Cloud Starters to JHipster?

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster

I have a JHipster project, i want to use google cloud starters on prod profile but the maven can not resolve these starters.

```
<profile>
        <id>prod</id>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-storage</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.2.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-sql-mysql</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.2.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <build>

        </build>
        <properties>

        </properties>
    </profile>
```

Comment: You should not need to specify versions because it's part of imported dependencies from spring cloud. The 2 artifacts are in maven central, how do you run maven when it fails?

Comment: i was not able to run the mvn,anyway they are resolved if i take them out of the profiles ..